# How to stop jQuery Slides in a certain point?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have 5 slides, I need the slideshow to loop once through all the 5 slides, land again in slide #1 and stop there.
How can I do this?
The only ways I can interact with the slideshow I read on the documentation, is when creating it, I.E. `$("#slide").slides({ /* options here */ })`
But how can I interact with the slideshow once it started?

PS: I'm using jQuery Slides: http://slidesjs.com/

Comment: A chunk of code would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding to @Fredy31's comment, what library are you using?

Comment: @bfink jQuery slides: http://slidesjs.com/

Comment: @Fredy31: it's not much more than what I already wrote here. It just creates the slideshow on load with that code, and I don't know how to make it stop later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:
http://groups.google.com/group/slidesjs/browse_thread/thread/48ce26142e4a9280#

That answers how to loop it once through.  If you put a copy of your first slide as your last slide and loop it once through, I think you will reach the desired effect.