# animationComplete option not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because everything seem to work fine, except the `animationComplete()` option which I can't even get to run a simple alert. I actually want to use this option to stop my slideshow after one loop (and then finish on the first frame), but before I can do that I need `animationComplete()` to work. Here's my attempt to make an alert which doesn't return anything at all:

```
$('.slides_container').after('<div id="slides-nav" class="pagination">').cycle({
    animationComplete: function(current) {
        alert('alerted');
    },
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    pause: true,
    pager: '#slides-nav'
});
```

At the end of the day I'm looking to loop the rotation once through, and then pause on the first slide. I just figure this is the first hurdle I've come to so I can't move much beyond this point until I figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm looking to accomplish the same as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317206/how-to-stop-jquery-slides-in-a-certain-point/8319079#8319079) when it's all said and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm if I'm right I think you are confusing two plugins, each of them have different ways to use callbacks, you are using the cycle jquery plugin and animationComplete belongs to slidejs so try using 'after' and not animationComplete, try this:

```
$('.slides_container').after('<div id="slides-nav" class="pagination">').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    pause: true,
    pager: '#slides-nav',
    after: alert('alerted')
});
```

Comment: Wow. That's not embarrassing or anything. Apparently the website in question in linking to both SlidesJS and jQuery Cycle Plugin, and I just went with the first thing I saw (SlidesJS). 

Thanks for catching that! Now I just need to get the slideshow to stop on the first slide after one loop through.

Comment: Still though I suppose this is the right answer to my original question so I'll mark it as so.

Comment: check this page http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html is an example of their callback and I think their example works "after slide 1 passed" just copy and work with that :) good luck and no worries it happens to all!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just something like this:

```
$('.slides_container').after('<div id="slides-nav" class="pagination">').cycle({
    autostopCount: $('img',this).length+1,
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    pause: true,
    pager: '#slides-nav'
});
```

Comment: I see you noticed that I in fact was using the jQuery Cycle plugin as well. I tried using `autostopCount: $('img',this).length+1,`, but it didn't seem to do anything. I see what you were going for though. I'd try to rewrite it myself but I don't have my jQuery syntax down well enough to figure it out...

Comment: Hey Roasted, just wanted to say this in fact DOES work. My problem was that I was using divs for my slides. Once I adjusted the selector accordingly everything worked great. Thanks!!